# Python Selenium - Find Input Field after Label

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, dynamic

i need to find an Input field after an Label. Id and Name are dynamic and changes every Login.

HTML:

```
<label for="EveryTimeDifferent">LabelText</label>
<div>
    <div>
        <input name="EveryTimeDifferent" id="EveryTimeDifferent">
    </div>
</div>
```

Python:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='LabelText']//following::input[1]")
```

Comment: Your XPath (or simplified `//label[text()='LabelText']/following::input`) should work. Share exception log as well

Comment: Hi JaSON, thx your right, now i see the element is found but the Send_Keys dont work. My try:

test = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[text()='LabelText']/following::input")
print(test.tag_name)
test.send_keys("Test")

Comment: Python Print out the Tag Name Input, so long so correct but send_keys is skipped.

Comment: There might be several input fields. Check `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[text()='LabelText']/following::input")))`. Is it prints `1`? You need to select the one that is currently visible

Comment: Thx a lot :) - No its 64, there unfortunately a lot of Inputs on the loaded content. I though the following::input means that it only looks for the Next Input after the Label with LabelText is found. Is there another way to do this?

Comment: Oh, yeah... This will select all the following input fields) Try `print(len(driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[text()='LabelText']/following-sibling::div//input")))`. You also can try to [wait](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/waits.html#explicit-waits) for `element_to_be_clickable`

Comment: With the Adjustments it shrinks from 64 Inputs to 2

Comment: Ok. Try `driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[text()='LabelText']/following-sibling::div//input")[1].send_keys("Test")`

Comment: JaSON thank u so much, it works now :)

Answer (score -1):

well first of you'll need to find something that stays the same each session on the given website. I assume something stays the same in the said label in the given example. You could use BeautifulSoup and find the label with bs4's HTML parsing functions (You'll need to create a local string representation of the HTML code from the website for the BeautifulSoup() instance to be created).
That'd be something like:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(HTML_SRC_STR, 'html.parser')
soup.find('<your_label_tag'>' ...)
```

The docs of bs4 will explain it way better: https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/